# Ubuntu 23 Modify Contents of "Show Applications"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm a newbie Linux user (but a moderately advanced PC user in general), and I'm trying to figure out how to modify the contents of the "Show Applications" menu. I've already downloaded AppEditor, but it hasn't helped. I'm trying to re-order the apps and also create folders. I've looked up "~/usr/share/applications", but this folder doesn't seem to hold any solutions for me -- none that I discern, anyway. "~/.local/share/applications" is also unhelpful, as there's nothing in it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I have had some success with dconf (System Editor for Ubuntu)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: How did you use AppEditor? Did it do anything at all? What IS inside those locations that you did not recognize? Please be as specific and complete as you can be regarding the things you've tried. Often HOW they failed can be very helpful in finding and solving the real problem.

Comment: Search for (Google) second . That is what I did

Comment: Dconf has a variety of settings of which gnome is one.  To do more requires an answer which will be quickly downvoted

Comment: AppEditor could do nothing I was trying to do, which is change the order of apps in the Show Applications screen, and also create app folders within it.

As for "~/usr/share/applications", it doesn't seem to correlate at all with the Show Applications screen, at least not in any way I can discern. It has a great, great many files in it, while my Show Applications screen doesn't. And I didn't see anything that looked like something that could change app order or create folders.

Comment: As for dconf, I looked into it, but I've yet to figure out how to install it. I'm a Linux newbie. I'm far from hopeless, but if there's no deb, flatpak, or snap, I'm lost. I found a GUI for dconf with an auto-install, but not dconf itself. I didn't see a deb or snap, but I have yet to check FlatHub.

Comment: If not that, then I do not have another suggestion

Comment: It looks like there might be some GNOME extensions that help with this. I'll have to experiment when I get home from work.